# Why am i getting two MY ACCOUNT on my nav bar using sec:authorize ="isAnonymous()"

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">SHOPPING CART</a></li>
    <li><a sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" th:href="@{/login}">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
    <li><a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:href="@{/myProfile}">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
    <li><a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:href="@{/logout}">LOGOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:sec="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head th:fragment="common-header">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <title>Le's Bookstore</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="/css/non-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="icon" href="/image/applie-touch-icon.png" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div th:fragment="navbar">
            <div class="page-top"
                style="width: 100%; height: 20px; background-color: #f46b42;"></div>
            <!-- Static navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LE'S BOOKSTORE</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded="false">BOOKS <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Browse the bookshelf</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Store hours &#38; Directions</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>

                                </ul></li>
                            <form class="navbar-form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Book title" />
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                            </form>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">SHOPPING CART</a></li>
                            <li><a sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" th:href="@{/login}">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
                            <li><a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:href="@{/myProfile}">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
                            <li><a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:href="@{/logout}">LOGOUT</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!--/.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
        </div>
        
        <div th:fragment="body-bottom-scripts">
        <script
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters your namespaces are wrong they point to `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`, secondly when you are anonymous you are also authenticated, as anonymous but still authenticated. What you want is to use `isFullyAuthenticated` or add an `!isAnonymous` to the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Your namespace is not correct. You may need to add thymeleaf & springsecurity5 as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">

<!-- head, body, etc -->

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use !isAuthenticated(). Edit your code like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#">SHOPPING CART</a></li>
  <li><a sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()" th:href="@{/login}">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
  <li><a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:href="@{/myProfile}">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
  <li><a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:href="@{/logout}">LOGOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```